# Apache Sling giving access denied error when uploading a file

Tags: jsp, file-upload, jcr, sling

By below command I created the node

```
curl -u admin:admin -F"sling:resourceType=fileu/script" -F"title=node for file upload" http://localhost:8080/fileu/mynode
```

by below commands I added resourceType

```
curl -X MKCOL -u admin:admin http://localhost:8080/apps/fileu
curl -X MKCOL -u admin:admin http://localhost:8080/apps/fileu/script
```

the script i.e. JSP page was added by the following command

```
curl -u admin:admin -T fileu.script/html.jsp http://localhost:8080/apps/fileu/script/html.jsp
```

the code inside the JSP page is:

```
    <html>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="/fileu" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="*" />
    <input type="hidden" name="*@TypeHint" value="nt:file" />
    <input type="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I access the script by the following URL

```
http://localhost:8080/fileu/mynode.html
```

and I get error when I upload the file, in browser:

```
Error while processing /fileu

Status  
500
Message 
javax.jcr.AccessDeniedException: Access denied.
Location    /fileu
Parent Location /
Path    
/fileu
Referer http://localhost:8080/fileu/mynode.html
ChangeLog   
<pre></pre>
```

What is the issue? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your current user is 'anonymous'. Make sure 'anonymous' is permitted to add file or node.

Comment: To check that I think I will have to execute this command: 'curl http://localhost:8080/fileu/mynode.acl.json'

but when I ran that command I got HTTP-500

Comment: Could you please help in finding out how to find the permissions for 'anonymous'

Comment: By default, 'anonymous' is not permitted to create new node- a file is a node too. Also this credential is not allowed sending some administrative requests like '.../node.acl.json'. In your browser log in as 'admin' and then try uploading file, by this your sling session is an administrative one and you will be permitted to create new node.

Comment: It's better no to change 'anonymous' permissions. I prefer to create new user or group to do actions you want.

Comment: thanks a lot Babak. My issue got resolved by the directions you suggested. I added the request header field i.e. Authorization: Basic <my_base64_encoded_username:password> and the file was uploaded as a new node.